# jqgrid data is not displaying in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am getting only the layout of jqgrid but it is not displaying the data inside it.can you please help me.
My code in aspx page,

```
<style type="text/css">    
    body, html { font-size: 80%; }     
       </style>


       <script type ="text/javascript" >

       jQuery(document).ready( function(){ 
           var mydata = [
    { id: "1", invdate: "2010-05-24", name: "test", note: "note", tax: "10.00", total: "2111.00" },
    { id: "2", invdate: "2010-05-25", name: "test2", note: "note2", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "21.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "11", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "12", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "13", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "14", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "15", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "16", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "17", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "18", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "19", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "21", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "22", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "23", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "24", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "25", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "26", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "27", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "28", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "29", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" }
];
           jQuery("#list47").jqGrid({
               data: mydata,
               datatype: "local",
               height: 150,
               rowNum: 10,
               rowList: [10, 20, 30],
               colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
               colModel: [
    { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int" },
    { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90, sorttype: "date", formatter: "date" },
    { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100 },
    { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float", formatter: "number" },
    { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
    { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
    { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false }
],
               pager: "#plist47",
               viewrecords: true,
               caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
           });
       }); 

       </script>
```

```
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the data is not getting loaded from the array passed to the 'data' option. Adding data through the following 'for' loop works,

```
for(var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
  jQuery("#list47").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
}
```